# Uploading JPEG image via HTML form and PHP script seems to be setting the orientation flag in the EXIF data to 1 (or stripping it completely)

Tags: php, html, phpbb3

I'm working on some gallery software, but I'm having an issue where the 'Orientation' flag in the EXIF data following an image upload is always being set to 1 (meaning "do nothing") regardless of the orientation of the picture.
This means I cannot get the picture to display with the correct orientation.

Here are the salient parts of my upload form:

```
<form id="Upload" name="Upload" action="http://www.goosedalemodelflyingclub.co.uk/index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
...
<div class="uploadbox">
<label>Choose photo to upload:<input id="file_upload1" type="file" name="file_upload1" accept="image/*"></label>
<br>
<label>Name of Photo: (1) <span id="new_msg_name1"></span><br><input type="text" class="p_name" size="60" maxlength="40" id="new_name1" name="new_name1" value=""></label>
<br>
<label>Description:
    <span id="new_msg_desc1"></span><br>
    <textarea id="new_desc1" name="new_desc1" class="p_desc" rows="4" cols="70" maxlength="250" style="width: auto; height: auto;"></textarea>
</label>
<br>
<label>Who is able to view this picture:
    <select id="albpic_visib_upload1" name="albpic_visib_upload1">
        <option value="O">Me only</option>
        <option value="G">Forum only</option>
        <option value="W">Everyone</option>
    </select>
</label>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" onclick="return validateUploadForm(this)" id="NewPix1" name="NewPix1" value="Upload Photos to Current Album">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="#">
    <input type="button" name="cncl" id="cncl" value="Cancel">
</a>
<br>
</div>
...
<input type="hidden" id="p" name="p" value="MyGallery">
<input type="hidden" id="override" name="override" value="Y">
<input type="hidden" id="albumid" name="albumid" value="54321">
<input type="hidden" id="gfunc" name="gfunc" value="NewPix1">
<input type="hidden" id="pix_this_upload" name="pix_this_upload" value="15">
<input type="hidden" id="user_id_passed" name="user_id_passed" value="12345"></div>
</form>
```

I have a number of divisions having the class "uploadbox" to allow a number of photos to be uploaded at once (as given by pix_this_upload, may or may not be 15).
The JavaScript function validateUploadForm() is of no relevance - all it does is check the fields are filled in correctly and tells the user if there is anything wrong.

The pertinent section of my PHP script is as follows (including some debugging reporting to help me get to the bottom of this):

```
$formfiles = $request->file("file_upload$ii");
$tempfile = $formfiles['tmp_name']; // Temporary name of file (uploaded as)
...
$uploaded = @move_uploaded_file($tempfile, $fullpath); // Move the uploaded file to its permanent home and rename appropriately
...
$exif = exif_read_data($fullpath); // Get EXIF data
/*** DEBUG start ***/
$ff = $this->picsrootaddr;
$ff .= "application_$pictureid.log";
$debug_r = fopen($ff, "w");
fwrite($debug_r, "$path_o\n");
$xxr = print_r(array_values($exif), true);
fwrite($debug_r, "Debug 0: " . $xxr . "\n\n");
/*** DEBUG end for now ***/

if (isset($exif['Orientation']))
{
    $orientation = isset($exif['Orientation']); // Orientation
    fwrite($debug_r, "Debug 1: $orientation\n");
}
else
{
    if (isset($exif['IDF0']['Orientation']))
    {
        $orientation = $exif['IDF0']['Orientation'];  // Orientation
        fwrite($debug_r, "Debug 2: $orientation\n");
    }
    else
    {
        $orientation = EXIF_NOTHING; // Leave image as-is
        fwrite($debug_r, "Debug 3: $orientation\n");
    }
}

/*** DEBUG start ***/
fclose($debug_r);
/*** DEBUG end ***/
```

It's quite difficult to post the entire code as some of it is in a function, and there is a lot of checking going on (is_uploaded_file, etc).
Also, it may be noteworthy that the site uses phpBB3, and this blocks access to the superglobals in PHP, hence the use of this $request object.
This is instantiated by phpBB3 itself, so all I have to do is use it.

Here is a link to a photo that I have uploaded using the script (moved to a holding area so as not to interfere with my testing):
http://www.goosedalemodelflyingclub.co.uk/gallery_aux/original/43/pic176_DSCF4678.JPG

Here is a link to a script online that I found that displays its EXIF data:
http://regex.info/exif.cgi?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.goosedalemodelflyingclub.co.uk%2Fgallery_aux%2Foriginal%2F43%2Fpic176_DSCF4678.JPG
Note how the EXIF data does not include the orientation and appears to be highly stripped down.

This is an EXIF log file produced by debugging code I added to print the exif data to a file:
http://www.goosedalemodelflyingclub.co.uk/gallery_aux/application_176.log
Note how the 'Orientation' flag is being reported as 1.

I uploaded the same picture directly using FileZilla here:
http://www.goosedalemodelflyingclub.co.uk/stackoverflow/DSCF4678.JPG
Note how it displays with the correct orientation (in Google Chrome, anyway)

And here is its EXIF data report from the same website:
http://regex.info/exif.cgi?dummy=on&imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.goosedalemodelflyingclub.co.uk%2Fstackoverflow%2FDSCF4678.JPG

So somewhere along the line, the EXIF data is getting stripped meaning that I stand no chance of rotating or flipping the image to make it show correctly.

Can someone give me a steer in the right direction here please?
I've Googled this to death and this has turned up countless articles, tutorials and questions all of which essentially indicate that I'm not doing anything wrong.

PPS: Looks like a similar question here, if not the same, but no answer provided:
[No orientation in exif data - PHP image upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796170/no-orientation-in-exif-data-php-image-upload) - and it's about iOS anyway.

Comment: whats `$path_o` ? shouldn't it be `$fullpath`?

Comment: You're right - bad C&P on my part.  It's because that bit is in the function I mentioned.  Thanks!

Comment: TLDR - shorten the description down, and add more code

Comment: Done - also corrected the $path_o / $fullpath thing.

Comment: I think this may have something to do with phpBB3 - that version of the forum enforces the use of a $request->file() method instead of $_FILES[].  A test script outside of phpBB3 resulted in the EXIF data appearing to be uploaded successfully.  Have posted on the phpBB3 forums.  Hopefully this may help anyone else having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this, and thanks to everyone who had a look at it.
The problem was Failure To Read The Documentation Properly on my part.

In PHP, the imageflip() method returns a boolean to say whether it was successful or not, and modifies the image passed as a parameter in-place:
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imageflip.php

However, the imagerotate() method returns a resource to the rotated image and leaves the original unchanged:
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functi ... rotate.php

The mistake I was making was thinking that imagerotate() returned a success/failure Boolean and modified the image in-place like imageflip() does, but this is not the case.

Thought it was worth posting this in case anyone discovered this question and wanted to try and answer it, and also to prevent anyone else falling into the same trap.

The mistake was not in any of my posted code - it was elsewhere.